# How to manipulate dataset to get information from different tables?

Tags: sql-server, join, union, tableau-api

Currently my data is set up as a union of two tables.  The red rows are Table 1 and the blue rows are Table 2.  I am doing my union in SQL Server and am connecting this into Tableau.  I am using Excel right now to depict what I am seeing (left pivot table) more easily and what I want to see (right made-up pivot table).

The current pivot table is showing when filtered on a particular Plant/Project/Product, those are the components that go into the Product and those are the months in which the Products are due to the customer.  The values in the bottom row are the quantity of the Product that is due to the customer.  For example- in June, a quantity of 1 of the 150-100020-1000 product is due to the customer.  The quantities are showing up under a null component because that field isn’t in Table 2, as you can see in the blue rows.

I want those bottom row values to appear under literally any one of those components that are listed.  In this case, it’s only showing one set of Plant/Project/Product, but I would want the formula/code to pick up on that too when it’s evaluating what to output. In the example on the right side made-up pivot table, I have the quantities showing up under the component #100, but it can be under any of them as long as the Plant/Project/Product is equal in both tables. I also don't want the blank/null dates from Table 1 to show up, but they are tied to the components so I can't filter them out easily.

I've tried several types of joins and temporarily tables to get this working and keep coming up blank. How can I set up my dataset to get the view I want to see in Tableau?

Dataset and Current View + View I Want

[image]

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. Isolate the 1st subexpression that doesn't give what you expect. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you don't have a Component against a Qty. Hence for what you want somehow you need to create a Component. Perhaps this is possible using a FIXED calc, which would create this field across all records. If the value of Component doesn't matter create this calculation:

```
{MIN([Component])}
```

This should put 100 against each record.

If you also need to keep the existing Component value, when it exists, try a formula such as:

```
IFNULL([Component],{MIN([Component])})
```

Note I haven't tested any of this.